# How to get data from Firestore data on a website hosted on secure HTTPS protocol using Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore to save some customer data, and I populate it on my website. When I use "HTTP" protocol, I receive data from Firestore effortlessly. However, as soon as I switch over to the secure protocol, "HTTPS," I stop receiving the documents saved in Firestore.

Please help me understand how do I receive data in my secure "HTTPS" based website.

I have tried running my code on a Non-Secure "HTTP" based website, and the entire code is working just fine in that case. The issue appears when I switch to "HTTPS."

My Firestore Config File (I copied this exactly from GCP setup guide):

```
const config = {
    apiKey: "API-KEY",
    authDomain: "MY-DOMAIN.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://MY-DOMAIN.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "MY-DOMAIN",
    storageBucket: "MY-DOMAIN.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "SENDER-ID"
};
const default_app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
const db = firebase.firestore();
const settings = {/* your settings... */ timestampsInSnapshots: true };
db.settings(settings);
```

Here is the code I am using to populate my results:

```
var doc_ref = db.collection(collection).doc(document)

doc_ref.get().then(function(doc){
    if (doc.exists) {
        // do something
    } else {
        console.log('Document not Found')
    }
}
```

I expect to get data from Firestore on HTTPS secure website

Comment: Any messages in your browser console?

Comment: in your code snippet, you use `doc_ref` and test on `doc`

Comment: @Phil, I get a comment that "It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS SDK." all the time. Apart for this mebrowser ssage, I see nothing in my console.

Comment: @Salketer, I had missed writing a line of code in this question. Thanks for pointing it out. I have added it now. Please let me know if you find anything out of order now.

Comment: @Phil, I see no messages in my browser console.